# cancelled asyncio tasks result in "Task was destroyed but it is pending"

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

I am trying to write a job scheduler that can efficiently schedule M jobs across N cores.  As soon as one job completes, a new one should be immediately started.  Also, we should support timeout so that no task takes longer than a certain amount of time.  This is what I came up with the for the main loop:

```
import asyncio
import sys

max_concurrency = 4

async def _sleep_asynchronously(time):
    index, seconds = time
    await asyncio.sleep(seconds)
    return (index, seconds)

def select_invocations(waiting, num_running):
    count = max_concurrency - num_running
    selected = waiting[:count]
    waiting = waiting[count:]
    return selected, waiting

async def _run_everything_asynchronously():
    tasks = []
    timeouts = [ 4, 3, 1, 2, 0.5, 7, 0.25, 3, 2, 1, 4.5, 5]
    timeouts = list(enumerate(timeouts))

    pending, waiting = select_invocations(tasks, 0)
    running = {_sleep_asynchronously(timeout) for timeout in timeouts}

    while len(running) > 0:
        try:
            done, running = await asyncio.wait(running, timeout=0.5, return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED)
            if not done:
                for r in running:
                    r.cancel()
                    await r
            else:
                for d in done:
                    index, timeout = await d
                    print("Index {} finished waiting for {} seconds".format(index, timeout))

        except asyncio.CancelledError as e:
            running.clear()

        if len(waiting) > 0:
            pending, waiting = select_invocations(tasks, len(running))
            running = {_sleep_asynchronously(timeout) for timeout in timeouts}

if 'win32' in sys.platform:
    asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(asyncio.WindowsProactorEventLoopPolicy())

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
rc = loop.run_until_complete(_run_everything_asynchronously())
loop.close()

sys.exit(0)
```

If I run this, this is my output:

```
Index 6 finished waiting for 0.25 seconds
Index 4 finished waiting for 0.5 seconds
Index 9 finished waiting for 1 seconds
Index 2 finished waiting for 1 seconds
Task was destroyed but it is pending!
task: <Task pending coro=<_sleep_asynchronously() done, defined at D:\src\asynciotest.py:6> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[<TaskWakeupMethWrapper object at 0x000001E74D13BDF8>()]>>
Task was destroyed but it is pending!
task: <Task pending coro=<_sleep_asynchronously() done, defined at D:\src\asynciotest.py:6> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[<TaskWakeupMethWrapper object at 0x000001E74D352438>()]>>
Task was destroyed but it is pending!
task: <Task pending coro=<_sleep_asynchronously() done, defined at D:\src\asynciotest.py:6> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[<TaskWakeupMethWrapper object at 0x000001E74D37F9D8>()]>>
Task was destroyed but it is pending!
task: <Task pending coro=<_sleep_asynchronously() done, defined at D:\src\asynciotest.py:6> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[<TaskWakeupMethWrapper object at 0x000001E74D37FBE8>()]>>
Task was destroyed but it is pending!
task: <Task pending coro=<_sleep_asynchronously() done, defined at D:\src\asynciotest.py:6> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[<TaskWakeupMethWrapper object at 0x000001E74D3A15B8>()]>>
Task was destroyed but it is pending!
task: <Task pending coro=<_sleep_asynchronously() done, defined at D:\src\asynciotest.py:6> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[<TaskWakeupMethWrapper object at 0x000001E74D3E7498>()]>>
Task was destroyed but it is pending!
task: <Task pending coro=<_sleep_asynchronously() done, defined at D:\src\asynciotest.py:6> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[<TaskWakeupMethWrapper object at 0x000001E74D3E74C8>()]>>
```

What am I missing here?  How do I properly clean up the tasks which were cancelled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you cancel a task and `await` on it, unless caught, it will throw a `CancelledError`.

Your current code takes the first `CancelledError` and clears the running list, without cancelling the rest:

```
except asyncio.CancelledError as e:
    running.clear()
```

Instead of awaiting, just cancel all of them:

```
for r in running:
    r.cancel()
```

Comment: Ok, good catch.  There's also another problem with my code, but not important for this case.  In my real program, these async functions are subprocesses, and even when I do it the way you suggest, all of the cancelled subprocesses still complain.  I had to add back the await which throws, but wrap just that await with an except clause that does nothing.  So it seems like (for subprocesses at least), the await is still necessary.

Comment: It's because the cancellation didn't finish. You can `await asyncio.wait(runners)` after cancelling.